# Is there any way to export a AR table to method calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some data in an AR table that I inserted manually through my application, but I'd like to export it as a bunch of `model.create!(...)` statements (in other words, I want a file of method calls to recreate the database as-is), is there a way to do this automatically (through the console, rake, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do something with a simple hack like this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  puts "User.create!(YAML.load(<<END))\n#{user.attributes.to_yaml}\nEND"
end
```

You can generate with `rails runner`:

```
rails runner user_export.rb >> db/seeds.rb
```